# C Error: C2040: 'customerPtr' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'customer *'

Tags: c, struct, initialization, variable-assignment

Pretty new to C. I keep getting this error when I run the code my instructor gave us to start with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Create a struct for customers
struct customer
{
char lastName[15];
char firstName[15];
unsigned int customerNumber;
};


struct customer customerRecord;
struct customer *customerPtr;
struct customer other;

customerPtr = &customerRecord;

//typedef struct customer to customer
typedef struct customer customer;

char main()
{
//customerRecord.lastName = Flacco;

}
```

I get the error 
error C2040: 'customerPtr' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'customer *'

I have read other posts similar to this but I guess I don't understand the answers in
 relation to their programs.

Thanks!

Comment: What line of code gives you the error message?

Comment: In all my years of coding, and using forums like this one and c.l.c,  I have never seen `char main()`. Thanks for the chuckle :)

Comment: Note that including `<stdlib.h>` doesn't give you any benefit compared to including it once.

Comment: As diagnosed by the answer, `customerPtr = &customerRecord;` is the trouble; you can't write assignments at global scope. You may reasonably be wondering where the `int` comes from, though. I think the compiler must be assuming that the type of the (second declaration of) `customerPtr` is `int` since you didn't specify a type, and that is not the correct type for the assignment, hence the warning. I'm surprised you aren't getting an error about redefining `customerPtr` but the compiler is at liberty to diagnose anything as long as it gives at least one diagnostic for an incorrect program.

Answer (score 4):

This assignment is wrong (assignment is not allowed at global scope):

```
customerPtr = &customerRecord;
```

you should change it with:

```
...
struct customer customerRecord;
struct customer *customerPtr = &customerRecord;  /* definition & initialization */
struct customer other;
...
```

or

```
struct customer customerRecord;
struct customer *customerPtr;  /* definition */
struct customer other;

...

int main()
{
  customerPtr = &customerRecord;  /* initialization */

  ...
}
```

Also return type of `main` should be `int`